# Merging different classes/clusters in one single raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, spatial-analyst, arcgis-9.3, clustering

I've created a signature file with 8 clusters and performed an unsupervised classification in ArcGIS 9.3. Later I have grouped values (spatial) classes together to form 4 classes I needed (in symbology) but that just "colors" them the same, they're still treated as separate categories. I need to merge them to have only 4 groups/categories.

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Reclassify](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=6422&pid=6415&topicname=Reclassify) tool. Alternately you can do the [reclassification from the Spatial Analyst toolbar](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using%20the%20ArcGIS%20Spatial%20Analyst%20toolbar%20to%20reclassify%20data).